# Python Tkinter scrollbar issue

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tcl

I am recieving a strange bahavior and exception of the **Tkinter scrollbar**.
My GUI basically uses a Tkinter *Text Widget* which is related/referenced to the scrollbar.

```
    self.textFrame = Tkinter.LabelFrame (self.mainFrame,padx=0,pady=0,width=200,height=100)
    self.textFrame.grid(row=5, column =1, sticky = "NW", padx = 5, pady = 10)
    self.consLable = Tkinter.Label (self.textFrame,text = "Log-Console:",font ="Verdana 8 bold")
    self.consLable.grid (row =6,column =1, sticky = "NW", padx = 5, pady = 1)
    self.consText= Tkinter.Text(self.textFrame, wrap = "word")
    self.consText.grid(row =7,column =1, rowspan =4)
    self.consText.tag_configure("stderr", foreground="#b22222")
    self.scrollText= Tkinter.Scrollbar(self.textFrame,command = self.consText.yview)
    self.scrollText.grid(row =7,column =2,rowspan =4,sticky='NSEW')
    self.consText.config(yscrollcommand = self.scrollText.set)

    # Referencing output location of the console "print or sys.stderr" methods
    sys.stdout = gemeindesteckbrief__SupportTools__.TextRedirector(self.consText, "stdout")
    sys.stderr=  gemeindesteckbrief__SupportTools__.TextRedirector(self.consText, "stderr")
```

In the Text Widget itself *python console entries* are inserted using `sys.stdout`and `sys.stderr`. To insert the text a  support class is used which overwrites the `.sys.stderr.write`or `print`method and writes the text into the Tkinter text widget.

```
class TextRedirector(object):
def __init__(self,widget, tag):
    self.targetwidget = widget
    self.targettag = tag

#@Override the sys.stdout & sys.stderr methods to write to the text widget instead of the python console
def write(self, str):
    self.targetwidget.configure(state="normal")
    self.targetwidget.insert("end", str, (self.targettag,))
    self.targetwidget.configure(state="disabled")
```

Inserting the text into the Text Widget works as expected, also clicking into the Widget and scrolling using the mouse wheel works fine, also using the up and down buttons of the scrollbar works. All trouble starts using the bar and trying to slide up and down. The effect is a **TclError: expected floating-point number but got "0,0028"**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3156, in yview
self.tk.call((self._w, 'yview') + what)
TclError: expected floating-point number but got "0,0028"
```

Comment: Sounds like a number gets formated with the local decimal point (`,`).

Comment: If you change `self.scrollText.set` to `lambda s: self.scrollText.set(s.replace(',', '.'))` Does it change something? Maybe you need to wrap the methods. But I do not know why the error occurs.

Comment: What precise versions of Python, Tkinter, Tk and Tcl are involved here?

Comment: Python Version 2.6.5; The Tkinter - Version="$Revision: 73770 $" TCL maybe 8.5...I don't know exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I just found a kind of workaround solution to my problem
Tkinter seems to have problems concerning multple threads.
So I just changed the `Tkinter.Scrollbar` to `ttk.Scrollbar`. 
The ttk module is a extended version of Tkinter and solves some
weird behaviors of the Tkinter module.

Look at http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.ttk.html

After changing the module of the widget everything works as expected!

*This solution is just a workaround of the actual issue but it works!!*